# Overpass API python wrapper to run requests on the endpoint of overpass-turbo

Tags: python, csv, mysql

we have with Overpass API python wrapper a thin Python wrapper around the OpenStreetMap Overpass API  https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper

we have some Simple example:

```
import overpass
api = overpass.API()
response = api.Get('node["name"="Salt Lake City"]')
```

Note that you don't have to include any of the output meta statements. The wrapper will, well, wrap those.

we will get our result as a dictionary, which represents the JSON output you would get from the Overpass API directly.

```
print [(feature['tags']['name'], feature['id']) for feature in response['elements']]
[(u'Salt Lake City', 150935219), (u'Salt Lake City', 585370637), (u'Salt Lake City', 1615721573)]
```

we an specify the format of the response. By default, we will get GeoJSON using the responseformat parameter. Alternatives are plain JSON (json) and OSM XML (xml), as ouput directly by the Overpass API.

```
response = api.Get('node["name"="Salt Lake City"]', responseformat="xml")
```

updated **question:** can we also get cvs - can we perform a request like below with the python wrapper to the endpoint of overpass turbo?

```
[out:csv(::id,::type,"name","addr:postcode","addr:city",
"addr:street","addr:housenumber","website"," contact:email=*")][timeout:30];
area[name="Madrid"]->.a;
( node(area.a)[amenity=hospital];
  way(area.a)[amenity=hospital];
  rel(area.a)[amenity=hospital];);
out;
```

Comment: Once you have some data in a python dictionary it is pretty straight forward to write it to a CSV file with the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html). In addition it might be worth taking the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour), since your question is well written it doesn't really focus on GIS - rather general Python usage, which is probably better answered on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: hello dear Roper Maps - many many thanks - great options ahead with this python aproach

Comment: dear RoperMaps - many many thanks for the quick reply - i hust have added some more detailed question - see the csv-request.- Guess that i can run this with the wrapper toooo?